# Rails obtener id en una relacion uno a muchos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, orm, vistas, relaciones

estoy tratando de obtener un parametro para salvar el la bd, estoy trabajando una relacion uno a muchos entre dos modelos.

gift.rb

```
class Gift < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :sponsor
end
```

sponsor.rb

```
class Sponsor < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :pet
 has_many :gifts
end
```

mi routes.rb esta definido de la siguiente manera

```
resources :sponsors do
 resources :gifts
end
```

mi gift_controller.rb

```
def create

    @gift = Gift.new(gift_params)
    @gift.assign_attributes({:status => 'Iniciado'})

    if @gift.save
        flash[:success] = "Regalo salvvado"
        redirect_to sponsor_gifts_path(@sponsor)
    else
        flash[:danger] = "Ocurrió un error"
        redirect_to sponsors_path()
    end
end
```

mi sponsor_controler.rb

```
def new
 @sponsor = Sponsor.new(sponsor_params)
 @sponsor.assign_attributes({:user_id => current_user.id})
 @sponsor.assign_attributes({:pet_id => params[:mascot]})

 if (Sponsor.where(:user_id => current_user.id).where(:pet_id => params[:mascot]).count == 0)
     if @sponsor.save
         flash[:success] = "Felicidades usted, ahora es Padrino. Gracias por apoyarnos"
         redirect_to new_sponsor_gift_path(@sponsor)
     else
         flash[:danger] = "Ocurrió un error no se ha podido apadrinar la mascota"
         redirect_to sponsors_path()
     end
 else
     flash[:danger] = "Ya eres Pasdrino de esa Mascota"
     redirect_to sponsors_path()
 end
end
```

Lo que necesito es el parametro que estoy logrando pasar por url a la vista_new de gitf que es el identificador del sponsor recien creado, que necesito como parametro para la creacion de un gift.

La vista de creacion es la siguiente:
new.html.reb

```
<%= simple_form_for(Gift.new, :url => { :action => "create" }) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>
    <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present? %>



    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
          <div class="form-inputs">
            <%= f.input :description, label: 'Descripción del Regalo', as: :text, :input_html => {:style => 'width: 100%', :rows => 5, class: 'response-project'} %>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>




    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
      <hr>
      <center>

            <%= f.submit 'Aceptar', :class => 'btn btn-info' %>
          <!-- 
          <%= link_to 'Cancel', url_for(:back), :class => 'btn btn-default' %>
           -->
      </center>
      <p>
    </div>
 <% end %>
```